# Active Account count on specific date in MDX

Tags: mdx

I have a situation where I need to get active account count on a specific date.

I have start date end date in SQL it looks like

```
select count(account) where start_date <=@date and end_date >=@date
```

In MDX, I tried below one

```
 AGGREGATE( 
            {
             NULL:LINKMEMBER
                            (
                             [DATE].[YQMWD].CURRENTMEMBER
                             , [StartDate].[YQMWD]
                            )
            }
            * 
            {
             LINKMEMBER
                       (
                        [DATE].[YQMWD].CURRENTMEMBER
                        , [EndDate].[YQMWD]
                       ):NULL
            }
            , ([Measures].[AccountCount])
       )
```

This Code is returning me perfect on date level only  but once I  am traversing to Week or Month it is considering the whole month of the active value. But during the selected month period many account getting deactivate.
 If anybody faced this kind of measure before  like 
"Active value on specific date" .

Comment: (upped) interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

I thought about the following but then noticed that you are dealing with two distinct dimensions `[StartDate]` and `[EndDate]` so using the range operator `:` is incorrect:

```
 AGGREGATE( 
     UNION(
       {
         NULL
         :
         LINKMEMBER(
             [DATE].[YQMWD].CURRENTMEMBER
           , [StartDate].[YQMWD]
         )
       }
      ,{
         LINKMEMBER(
             [DATE].[YQMWD].CURRENTMEMBER
           , [EndDate].[YQMWD]
         )
         :
         NULL
       }
     )
   , ([Measures].[AccountCount])
)
```

If we look in the definition of `LINKMEMBER` then it says the following:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146058.aspx

> The LinkMember function returns the member from the specified
>   hierarchy that matches the key values at each level of the specified
>   member in a related hierarchy. Attributes at each level must have the
>   same key cardinality and data type. In unnatural hierarchies, if there
>   is more than one match for an attribute's key value, the result will
>   be an error or indeterminate.

So it makes sense the behaviour you are encountering - if `[DATE].[YQMWD].CURRENTMEMBER` is a week, then the key of this member is not going to map across to either `[StartDate].[YQMWD]` or `[EndDate].[YQMWD]`.

Moreover if a week is selected then how do you interpret this `sql` logic `where start_date <=@date and end_date >=@date` as a week is made up of 7 days so @date has 7 possibilities?

Maybe you could use `EXISTS` function inside the `LINKMEMBER` function so that only Date level members are used. Then we have this problem that `Exists` will return a set type but the first arg of `LINKMEMBER` needs to be of type member. So get hold of the first and last members using `Tail` and `Head` like so:

```
AGGREGATE( 
   {
     NULL
     :
     LINKMEMBER(
       HEAD(
         EXISTS(
           [DATE].[YQMWD].CURRENTMEMBER
          ,[DATE].[YQMWD].[Date]   ////<<if CURRENTMEMBER is a week then Exists will return a set of 7 Date members 
         )
       ,1                          ////<<if CURRENTMEMBER is a week then Head(..1) will return a set of 1 Date member - the first date in the week
       ).ITEM(0).ITEM(0)           ////<<this converts from single member set to a member
       , [StartDate].[YQMWD]
     )
   }
 * 
   {

    LINKMEMBER(
       TAIL(
         EXISTS(
           [DATE].[YQMWD].CURRENTMEMBER
          ,[DATE].[YQMWD].[Date] 
         )
       ,1    
       ).ITEM(0).ITEM(0)    
       , [EndDate].[YQMWD]
     )
     :NULL
   }
 , ([Measures].[AccountCount])
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I think the query with performance is a pain on the neck. its taking a lot of time to execute.Is there any way to improve it .

Comment: We can try to improve the performance - but does the second script in my post answer your initial question?

Comment: yes, i understand, 2ndscript will work as because on each level it will consider the tails of the members.Indirectly if you consider the code will look as below : with member [Measures].[X] as AGGREGATE( { NULL:LINKMEMBER ( [DATE].[YQMWD].CURRENTMEMBER , [StartDate].[YQMWD] ) } * { LINKMEMBER ( [DATE].[YQMWD].CURRENTMEMBER , [EndDate].[YQMWD] ):NULL } , ([Measures].[AccountCount]) )

    member [Measures].[Y]
     as 
     ( ClosingPeriod([Date].[YQMWD].[Date], [Date].[YQMWD].CurrentMember)
, [Measures].[X] )

select [Measures].[X] on 0, [Date].[YQMWD].allmembers on 1

from cubename

Comment: But if in date dimension we will consider Tail and Head function it will kill the performance.Moreover the exact thing I am looking for in better way relate to performance as I mentioned in above code ..Please suggest me what i can do

Answer (score 0):

How about first checking for the type of input and then giving results? In this case `CoalesceEmpty` will check that and return the results. Used `FirstChild` function to fetch the first date always from the range.

```
CoalesceEmpty 
    (
    AGGREGATE
            (
                {NULL:LINKMEMBER([DATE].[YQMWD].CURRENTMEMBER.FIRSTCHILD.FIRSTCHILD.FIRSTCHILD.FIRSTCHILD, [StartDate].[YQMWD])}
                *
                {LINKMEMBER([DATE].[YQMWD].CURRENTMEMBER.FIRSTCHILD.FIRSTCHILD.FIRSTCHILD.FIRSTCHILD, [EndDate].[YQMWD]):NULL}
            , ([Measures].[AccountCount])
            )//--If it is a year
    ,
    AGGREGATE
            (
                {NULL:LINKMEMBER([DATE].[YQMWD].CURRENTMEMBER.FIRSTCHILD.FIRSTCHILD.FIRSTCHILD, [StartDate].[YQMWD])}
                *
                {LINKMEMBER([DATE].[YQMWD].CURRENTMEMBER.FIRSTCHILD.FIRSTCHILD.FIRSTCHILD, [EndDate].[YQMWD]):NULL}
            , ([Measures].[AccountCount])
            )//--If it is a quarter
    ,
    AGGREGATE
            (
                {NULL:LINKMEMBER([DATE].[YQMWD].CURRENTMEMBER.FIRSTCHILD.FIRSTCHILD, [StartDate].[YQMWD])}
                *
                {LINKMEMBER([DATE].[YQMWD].CURRENTMEMBER.FIRSTCHILD.FIRSTCHILD, [EndDate].[YQMWD]):NULL}
            , ([Measures].[AccountCount])
            )//--If it is a month
    ,
    AGGREGATE
            (
                {NULL:LINKMEMBER([DATE].[YQMWD].CURRENTMEMBER.FIRSTCHILD, [StartDate].[YQMWD])}
                *
                {LINKMEMBER([DATE].[YQMWD].CURRENTMEMBER.FIRSTCHILD, [EndDate].[YQMWD]):NULL}
            , ([Measures].[AccountCount])
            )//--If it is a week
    ,
    AGGREGATE
            (
                {NULL:LINKMEMBER([DATE].[YQMWD].CURRENTMEMBER, [StartDate].[YQMWD])}
                *
                {LINKMEMBER([DATE].[YQMWD].CURRENTMEMBER, [EndDate].[YQMWD]):NULL}
            , ([Measures].[AccountCount])
            )//--If it is a date
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Sourav, This code will fix issue .. But killing performance. Its taking more than 15 minutes to get the result.Any idea about better data modelling..

Comment: The culprit is `LinkMember`. Is there no direct relation between the `Date` dimension and the measure `AccountCount`?

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti - seems like a lot of copied code blocks in this possible answer: `HEAD` and `EXISTS` in my answer basically means there is no need for this. Also in the future what if a new hierarchy gets added to `YQMWD` - the developer will need to remember to amend this measure as well.

Comment: Its not *exactly* copied, but to an some extent, yes, repetitive code. I am using `FirstChild` function which is a shortcut to what you are doing. Also in your code, `EXISTS` is used, which might be a little slow `CoalesceEmpty` will work like the SQL - COALESCE where the next branch will be evaluated only when the current branch yields empty results. I am not claiming it to be a better answer...just a different flavor :)

Comment: But I think the main trouble lies elsewhere. The data model is to blame.

Comment: I agree with everything you say Sourav. `EXISTS` in mine could be slow: although exists with two hierarchies from the same dimension should be ok performance wise. This startDate and endDate dimensions seem pretty unusual, so yes maybe not the most textbook data model.